# Vue - named exports in *.vue files are ignored

Tags: javascript, module, vue.js

I am getting warnings in the console that the:

> named exports in *.vue files are ignored.

On looking around about the problem I came across [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/708)  where it is suggested that if I upgrade the vue loader to the **version 8.3.1** that all the warnings are gone. On checking the package.json file in the `node_modules/vue-loader` folder I saw that I already have that version:

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      {
        "raw": "vue-loader@^8.3.1",
        "scope": null,
        "escapedName": "vue-loader",
        "name": "vue-loader",
        "rawSpec": "^8.3.1",
        "spec": ">=8.3.1 <9.0.0",
        "type": "range"
      },
```

How can I fix this and get rid of this warnings?

Comment: I'm 99% sure you can't do this.

Comment: @EricGuan would you please explain briefly why we can't fix or get rid of these useless vue-loader warnings?